# Stop auto-scroll in Android browser!

Tags: browser, user-interface

I'm on a web page on my Android phone.  When I select a text input, the browser scrolls (about a quarter-screen every 10 seconds).  I don't know what causes this -- it doesn't look like any keys are stuck.

Further, it cancels the on-screen keyboard, so it's very hard to type.

This is *highly* bothersome.  Can anyone help me before I destroy my phone out of pure aggravation?

Comment: Can you provide some more info?  What phone?  Are you using the stock browser?

Comment: Is it only one webpage?

Comment: @Matthew Read: No, every webpage.

Comment: Have you tried using different browsers like Firefox, Dolphin etc etc

Comment: This almost sounds like it should be a bug report or a call to the device manufacturer. Have you tried factory resetting the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue on an HTC Desire (Android 2.3.3)

I had a crazy scrolling when tapping a text input field (the field get the focus but was scrolled out of the screen) and even worst: when entering values from the native keypad, each keytap was creating an arbitrary scroll..

After seeing this article I looked for some specific -webkit-transform tags and after removing them the issue is gone!

The lines were not even used, it was leftovers from previous attempts staying aside in a css file!!!